# Android app, showing a keyboard

Tags: android

I recently wrote my first app for android, and I created a listview for selecting an element from a list of about 500 items.  Since it's basically the default listview, it's searchable, and I can bring up the onscreen keyboard by holding down the menu button, but I was wondering if there was a way to bring up the keyboard automatically (and not make it freak out if the phone has a physical keyboard).  Does anyone know how I can do this?  I've been searching around and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your xml activity list definition (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, nevertheless; you could add a EditText above your list. When this EditText gets focus (which it will by default when you show your activity, presuming it's the first GUI component on the layout) it will also automatically trigger the software keyboard.

The neat thing of this approach is that it gets even more intuitive for the user that he or she can actually search the list by entering a search criteria.